# Force Woocommerce filter by attribute to show only attributes where search term is in title

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, widget

I'm using the below code to make wordpress search only by product titles. However, the woocommerce "Filter by Attributes" widget still shows filters as if the search was done on body text too.

So for example if I search "face" the results that show up all have "face" in the title but the Filter By Attribute widget will still show Chocolate as an attribute because there is a chocolate bar that has a description "Face it, we all love chocolate"

Then if you click the "Chocolate" filter, it will show no results, because the search is only showing results with "face" in the title.

I don't even know where to begin looking to change the behaviour of the filter by attributes widget.

```
// Search titles only 
function __search_by_title_only( $search, $wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($search)) {
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    }
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) {
        $term = esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($term));
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've cobbled together my own filter that plays nice with the above search (only the titles) and doesn't show any Brands that have items that don't have the keyword in the title. My only issue now is figuring out how to get the count of items.

```
<?php
 $searchterm = htmlentities($_GET["s"]);
 $filter_brand = htmlentities($_GET["filter_brand"]);
 $current = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $site_url = home_url();
 $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'title',
                's' => $searchterm
            );
    // The Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );



if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
echo'<div id="woocommerce_layered_nav-3" class="widget woocommerce widget_layered_nav woocommerce-widget-layered-nav">
<ul class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list">';
$unique_singler = array();
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
     $brand_terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'pa_brand' );
     $singler = array_values($brand_terms)[0];
     $name = $singler->name;
     $name_string = strtolower($name);
     $name_slug = str_replace(" ","-",$name_string);
// only create option if city hasn't been added yet
        if( ! in_array( $name, $unique_singler ) ) :
            // add city to array so it doesn't repeat
            $unique_singler[] = $name;
       ;?>
    <li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term <?php if (!($filter_brand == $name_slug) && !empty($filter_brand)) { echo 'hidden'; }?>">
    <?php echo '<a class="remover ';
    if ($filter_brand == $name_slug) { echo 'shown'; }
    echo '" href="'.$site_url.'/?s='.$searchterm.'&tags=1&ixwps=1&post_type=product"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>';
 ?><?php
    echo '<a class="dup" href="'.$current.'&filter_brand='.$name_slug.'">'.$name.'</a> <span class="count">(' .count($XXXXXXX). ')</span>';
 ?></li>
            <?php
    endif;?>                
                            <?php endwhile;?>
                </ul>       
</div>              
                            <?php else :?>
    <p>Nothing to see</p>
<?php endif; ?>

 <style>
 li.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item.wc-layered-nav-term a.remover {
    display:none;
}

li.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item.wc-layered-nav-term a.remover.shown {
    display:inline-block;
}

li.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item.wc-layered-nav-term.hidden
{
    display:none;
}

.x-sidebar .widget ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.085) !important;
}

ul.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list
{
     border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.085) !important;
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.085) !important;
}

.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list, li.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item.wc-layered-nav-term {
    margin-left:0 !important;
}

 .x-sidebar .widget ul li a {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
 }
 div#woocommerce_layered_nav-3 {
    margin: 0;
}

a.remover.shown i {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    margin-right:0.5em;
}
</style>
```